# iOS4 - problems using didDeselectAnnotationView on maps

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a pin on a map which shows the location name as an annotation.  When I click the annotation I'm using didDeselectAnnotationView to push a new view to the navigation controller, which works but I've found that I don't have to click on the annotation but clicking anywhere on the mapview triggers the event if the annotation is visible.

Is there a reason for that?  Am I missing something simple, or is it just because I only have one pin on the map at the moment?

Comment: Why don't you use a callout for the pin, with an accessory button inside?

Comment: Are you using didSelectAnnotationView or didDeselectAnnotationView?

Comment: I'll have a look at using the callout, I figured I was probably going about it the wrong way.  Thanks for the pointer.